# Using Selenium Grid to run Safari on MacOS Mojave

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, safaridriver

I'm trying to do a basic test using Selenium Grid to start Safari on a MacOS.

I have registered the node and its appears in my hub as the following.

[Hub Confirmating node is up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u34K9.png)

- browserTimeout: 0
- debug: false
- host: 10.120.45.211
- port: 5558
- role: node
- timeout: 1800
- cleanUpCycle: 5000
- maxSession: 5
- capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: Safari, maxInstances: 1,
  platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver,
  server:CONFIG_UUID: 1ba7b7b4-556c-430a-ab84-157...}
- downPollingLimit: 2
- hub: http://10.120.45.245:4444/grid/register
- id: http://10.120.45.211:5558
- nodePolling: 5000
- nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000
- proxy: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
- register: true
- registerCycle: 5000
- remoteHost: http://10.120.45.211:5558
- unregisterIfStillDownAfter: 60000

I understand that SafariDriver is now available directly within macOS and i'm using these steps to make sure it setup correctly.

*If you haven’t already done so, make the Develop menu available. Choose Safari > Preferences, and on the Advanced tab, select “Show Develop menu in menu bar.” For details, see Safari Help.
Choose Develop > Allow Remote Automation.
Authorize safaridriver to launch the XPC service that hosts the local web server. To permit this, manually run /usr/bin/safaridriver once and follow the authentication prompt.*

This is my JAVA code:

```
package SeleniumGrid;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class SafariRemoteAccess {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setBrowserName("Safari");

        //Point to hub
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc);

        // Go to website via NODE
        driver.get("https://www.hsbc.co.uk/");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I run the program i getting the following message.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "Safari",
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "1ba7b7b4-556c-430a-ab84-1574fc7ea584"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "Safari",
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "1ba7b7b4-556c-430a-ab84-1574fc7ea584"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Mishal-Shahs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9b:214f:9f0:2788%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.2', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 198 milliseconds**
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at SeleniumGrid.SafariRemoteAccess.main(SafariRemoteAccess.java:17)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "Safari",
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "1ba7b7b4-556c-430a-ab84-1574fc7ea584"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "Safari",
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "1ba7b7b4-556c-430a-ab84-1574fc7ea584"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Mishal-Shahs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9b:214f:9f0:2788%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.2', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-1MOS5JFR', ip: '10.120.45.245', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$4(NewSessionPipeline.java:76)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$5(NewSessionPipeline.java:75)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### Update

This is the code im using to setup the NODE on the MacOS machine:

```
java -Dwebdriver.safari.driver=/System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub 10.120.45.245:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -browser "browserName=Safari, platform=MAC, platformName=MAC, maxInstances=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your error stack trace if the *Selenium Grid* is on **Mac OS X** and to start the *Selenium Node* you are using the command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.safari.driver=/System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub 10.120.45.245:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -browser "browserName=Safari, platform=MAC, platformName=MAC, maxInstances=1"
```

why would you see the error log as (relates to **Selenium Grid**):

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Mishal-Shahs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9b:214f:9f0:2788%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.2', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Then again (first set relates to **Mac OS X** and second set relates to **Windows 10**):

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Mishal-Shahs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9b:214f:9f0:2788%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.2', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-1MOS5JFR', ip: '10.120.45.245', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

However the command you have used to initiate the *Selenium Grid Node* is error prone as it contains both:

- **platform=MAC**
- **platformName=MAC**

Assuming the *Selenium Grid Node* is being initiated from the **Windows 10** box the command should be:

```
java -Dwebdriver.safari.driver=C:\path\to\safaridriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub 10.120.45.245:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -browser "browserName=safari, platform=WINDOWS, maxInstances=1"
```

**Note**: Ensure **Safari** browser is installed within the **Windows 10**.